# How to fix "faulting module msvcr100.dll"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am getting this very strange crash on a client system for my C++ executable:

```
Faulting application Client.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module msvcr100.dll, version 10.0.30319.1, fault address 0x0008d635.
```

It works fine on a Windows 7 client, and it has above crash on a Windows Server 2003 R2, even after installing the visual C++ runtime environment. The first line of Client.exe is a `std::cout` command, so that I am very confident that the fault is not in the execution, but rather in dynamically loading the dlls. Unfortunately one of the libraries I link against is third party and not available with a static link to the runtime environment, so I can't statically link the executable.

Any advice on how to proceed on such an issue (and this one in particular)?

Comment: Memory dump + symbols into windbg, `!analyze -v`

Comment: I struggle to get a memory dump for this. DrWatson doesn't seem to produce one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinDbg actually pointed to the problem. Simply was some global variable that couldn't initialize due to a file missing on the client, and that was just the exception report.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/851511

And consider 32- vs 64-bit.

Finally, run "[depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)" (it should be available with all MSVisual Studio editions) against all three of:

- Your .exe
- Your 3rd party .dll
- Your msvc runtime .dll

Comment: Not sure how the link is helping. I am building for 32 bit on 64 bit, but the build process itself seems to be working for other executables... depends shows some random things missing (on the client some MSJava file, on the dev machine some IE files, none of them consequential). However, the msvcr100.dll is version 10.00.40219.325 on the dev machine and 10.0.30319.1 on the client, if that is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

What's the exception-code? I don't see third party DLL is the only cause, otherwise OS would have shown the error that particular DLL is missing.

Or is that third party DLL being loaded dynamically (somehow using `LoadLibrary`), or is a Managed DLL?

Use Dependency Walker, see if some DLL is missing. Try Tracing (F7) using depends itself, and see the debug output in lower pane of Depends.